# Concat file format not supported

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

Using VB I am trying to create a name for the file by concatenating together the words "NewEmployeesOut" with the short date and time of the day.  I am getting the following error System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.' Below is the Code I am currently using, it seems like VB does not like a character I am using in my concat function when trying to export the .txt file.

```
Private Sub btnWrite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWrite.Click
        Dim writeRecord As New StreamWriter

(New FileStream("NewEmployeesOut" & Date.Today.ToShortDateString & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString & ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        Dim EmployeeInformation1 As New EmployeeInformation()


        writeRecord.Write(EmployeeInformation1.LastName & "|")
        writeRecord.Write(EmployeeInformation1.FirstName & "|")
        writeRecord.Write(EmployeeInformation1.DepartmentNo & "|")
        writeRecord.Write(EmployeeInformation1.CreateUserName(EmployeeInformation1.FirstName, EmployeeInformation1.LastName) & "|")
        writeRecord.WriteLine(EmployeeInformation1.CreatePassword)

        writeRecord.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Program in a way that helps diagnosing bugs, you *really* want to see what that FileStream constructor argument looks like.  Use a variable.

Comment: The time portion of the created file name will contain a colon. A colon is not a valid character for Windows file names. You can format the time with a different separator.

Comment: ...and provide the full path of the file. If you think that the file will be (always) created in the root of your executable's installation path, you'll be disappointed. If you can write in that location when you deploy, that is.

Answer (score 1):

From MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file
The following characters are resevered.

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
 : (colon) 
" (double quote) 
/ (forward slash) 
\ (backslash) 
| (vertical bar or pipe) 
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

A file name formatted as follows will pass muster. The uppercase HH gives you 24 hour time.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fileName As String = "NewEmployeesOut" & Now.ToString(" MMMM dd, yyyy HH,mm") & ".txt"
    Debug.Print(fileName)
    File.CreateText(fileName)
End Sub
```

In the immediate window...

```
NewEmployeesOut December 10, 2020 18,07.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your short date probably looks like "31/12/2020" or "12/31/2020" which are no valid file names. Try something like

```
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim fileName As String = $"NewEmployeesOut_{now:yyyy-MM-dd}_{now:HHmm}.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks !  But will this work if I need to open the file for Append?  Basically trying to create a name for the file by concatenating together the words "NewEmployeesOut" with the short date.  Think my previous code had an invalid character, might of been a space, but noticed you replaced the space with an _ instead.

Comment: That is just a habit of mine not to have spaces within path names to simplify life (otherways it needs quotation marks around it if passed as an argument, it cannot easily be paste into a mail without breaking the link etc.). But I'm pretty sure your `.ToShortDateString()` is the code that returns the invalid characters. It has nothing to do with append or whatever file access you need - you just have to specify a valid file name. `2020-12-11.txt` is, `12/11/2020.txt` is not.

Comment: Getting This Error with the following code:   System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

pLastName was Nothing.

Comment: If pLastName.Length < 7 Then
            If random < 10 Then
                UserName = pLastName & pFirstName.First & random & random2
            Else
                UserName = pLastName & pFirstName.First & random & random2
            End If
        Else
            If random < 10 Then
                UserName = pLastName.Substring(0, 7) & pFirstName.First & random & random2
            Else
                UserName = pLastName.Substring(0, 7) & pFirstName.First & random & random2
            End If
        End If
        Return UserName

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the other question: It's the wrong place to post it, don't ask another question within a comment.

I think you have to learn a bit the basics first, read/watch some VB.Net tutorials and maybe some clean-code principles like the [clean-code-techniques](https://www.codingdojo.com/blog/clean-code-techniques). Your questions suggest that you don't know yet how to write simple code.

Try to structure what you are doing, avoid (like in your example) to copy 4 times the same lines of code but to create functions instead to encapsulate business logic. e.g. writing a file has nothing to do with assembling a file name, therefore the two things should not be conducted in the same method etc.

But this all said, here an idea how you could structure your code (from the comment not the main question), although I'm not too positive about the usability of the two random digits...

Usage:

```
Dim fileName As String = GetFileName("Smith", "John")
```

Methods/Properties:

```
Private Shared Function GetFileName(lastName As String, firstName As String) As String
    lastName = NormalizeAndCrop(lastName, 7)
    firstName = NormalizeAndCrop(firstName, 10)
    Dim randomNumber As Int32 = Randomizer.Next(0, 100)
    Return $"{lastName}{firstName}{randomNumber:00}"
End Function

Private Shared Function NormalizeAndCrop(text As String, length As Int32)
    'Check args
    If (length < 0) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(length), length, "A non-negative value expected!")
    If (text Is Nothing) OrElse (length = 0) Then Return String.Empty
    text = text.Normalize()
    'Copy only valid characters
    Dim result As New StringBuilder()
    For i As Int32 = 0 To text.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = text(i)
        If (IsValidFileNameChar(c)) Then
            result.Append(c)
            If (result.Length = length) Then
                Return result.ToString()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return result.ToString()
End Function

Private Shared Function IsValidFileNameChar(c As Char) As Boolean
    If (Char.IsControl(c)) Then Return False
    If (InvalidFileNameChars.IndexOf(c) > -1) Then Return False
    Return True
End Function

Private Shared ReadOnly Property Randomizer As Random = New Random(Environment.TickCount)
Private Shared ReadOnly Property InvalidFileNameChars As String = New String(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
```